# Count IP addresses from list

Tags: bash, ip, ip-address

My goal is to take a list of IPs, sometimes the list is just a single IP or it could be a range of IPs and count how many IPs there are in a list. We have another product that generates a list of IPs and we have been manually counting it using an Excel spreadsheet.

Using an existing post here on Stack, I have been attempting to incorporate it into a script that will accept a list. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/how-many-ip-addresses-are-in-a-given-range (See Pure Bash, 66 bytes).

Instead of grabbing two arguments on the command line $1 and $2, I pull a list into an array then enumerate through the array. If it is a single IP, it just adds 1 to the counter variable, if it is a range it uses the logic to convert the IPs to hex and counts them. I'm running into an issue where I am receiving errors.

I can't seem to figure out why this says "invalid number: printf: 229". I've read up on the expansion principle and I cannot seem to get my head around why it keeps throwing this error and calculating it improperly.

I've used this site for years, this is my first post. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
echo "Please supply a list of IP addresses"
echo "Example: " $0 "list.txt"
exit
fi

#Set some variables
LIST=($(cat ./$1))
COUNT=0

# Function for removing dots and converting to hex
p()(printf %02x ${1//./ })

# Enumerate the array of IPs
for RANGE in ${LIST[@]};do
IFS=- read IP1 IP2 <<< $RANGE

if [ -z $IP2 ]; then
COUNT=$[COUNT + 1]

else

r=$[0x`p $IP1`-0x`p $IP2`]
COUNT=$[COUNT + $[1+${r/-}]]

fi
done


echo "The count is" $COUNT
```

---

sample_range.txt:

```
192.168.47.11
192.168.48.10
192.168.65.228-192.168.65.229
192.168.65.234
192.168.65.239
192.168.65.241
192.168.65.244
192.168.80.220
192.168.93.231-192.168.93.235
192.168.93.237-192.168.93.239
192.168.103.222
```

This should result in 18, instead it gives me this output:

```
# ./rc.sh sample_range.txt 
: invalid number: printf: 229
: invalid number: printf: 235
: invalid number: printf: 239
The count is 707
```

Comment: Are your IP ranges always limited to a /24 subnet?

Comment: Hey Cyrus, no the subnets usually vary. I would think if the range was 10.10.65.1-10.11.65.255. It should still see 512 as an answer to the result of counting that range.

Comment: I assume that the result is 65791 ( 10.10.65.1-10._11_.65.255.)

Comment: Yes you are correct! I had a brain fart, I was thinking I incremented the third octet for that example.

Comment: Ah I upvoted it right away, but I didn't know about the check box. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPs are numbers base 256.

```
#!/bin/bash

ipdiff() {
  declare -i dec1 dec2 diff # set integer attribute
  dec1=$1*256*256*256+$2*256*256+$3*256+$4
  dec2=$5*256*256*256+$6*256*256+$7*256+$8
  diff=$dec2-$dec1+1
  counter=counter+$diff
}

declare -i counter

# read IP(s) from file, use . and - as separator
while IFS=".-" read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 b4; do
  if [[ -z $b1 ]]; then     # $b1 is empty (line with one IP)
    counter=counter+1
  else                      # $b1 is not empty (line with 2 IPs)
    ipdiff $a1 $a2 $a3 $a4 $b1 $b2 $b3 $b4
  fi
done < file

echo $counter
```

Output:

```
18
```

Comment: Very nice. That approach makes more sense. Thank you.

Comment: Cyrus, how does it read from the file? I rename my sample file "file" and I get this error. `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
3`

Comment: Which version of bash do you use?

Comment: Right now, I am using the one in Kali Linux 2. `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I fixed a bug (?). Please try again.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this error with bash 4.3.11 :(

Comment: I validated all 8 values are being passed to the function. From what I can tell (through the use of crude echo statements), that for whatever reason no value is being passed into $dec2 on line 6. Othewise, passing a value into dec1 works properly on line 5. The wheels fall off when performing the subtraction on line 7 with a null variable.

Comment: Very strange. Could you replace `< file` by `<<< "10.10.65.1-10.11.65.255"` to exclude problems with your file?

Comment: If I remove the $8 from the tail end of line 6, it processes (incorrectly but it does not error out). It doesn't like $8 for some reason.

Comment: That worked dandy. I wonder if it is inheriting a carriage return from the file?

Comment: Try this with your file: `dos2unix file` or `tr -d '\r' < file > file2; mv file2 file`.

Comment: Bobs your uncle! Awesome work Cyrus! I just learned a TON of stuff today. (dos2unix) worked like a charm.

Comment: In other news, the original script I posted works now as well. The issue were those carriage returns all along. This is an Occam's razor moment.